# why dont when add member to IPrincipal

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am adding a member to `IPrincipal`. I use `@User.LastName`

I get an error:

> CS1061: 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' does not contain a definition for 'LastName' and no extension method 'LastName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code:

```
public class LabPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    private readonly LabIdentity _identity;

    public LabPrincipal(LabIdentity identity)
    {
        _identity = identity;
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        return
            _identity.Roles.Any(
                current => string.Compare(current, role,      StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0);
    }

    public IIdentity Identity
    {
        get { return _identity; }
    }

    public LabIdentity Information
    {
        get { return _identity; }
    }

    public bool IsUser
    {
        get { return !IsGuest; }
    }

    public bool IsGuest
    {
        get { return IsInRole("guest"); }
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's probably because you have an `IPrincipal` which doesn't know about `LastName` - you might need to cast it to a `LabPrincipal` to get access to those additional properties

Answer (score 0):

`IPrincipal` is an interface that does not have the property "LastName". Only your `LabPrincipal` class does (from what we can see).

You'd have to convert `User` to `LabPrincipal` in your viewmodel to be able to get use it like that.

[Code behind]

```
yourViewModel.User = LabRepository.GetLabPrincipal(<user id>);
```

[Razor]

```
@Model.User.LastName
```